# cx_oracle connection lost on DB restart

Tags: python, oracle, oracle11g, cx-oracle

I'm connecting my API layer to Oracle DB using the cx_oracle connector, the issue here is that my DB machine keeps on restarting due to some other reasons.

I want to immune my API Layer to reestablish the connection or try to reconnect, what's the best possible solution to this?

Please don't suggest try and catch.

My connection code :

```
import cx_Oracle
connection_string = "{user}/{password}@{server}:{port}/{sid}".format(
    user=config.DB_USER,
    password=config.DB_PASSWORD,
    server=config.DB_HOST,
    port=config.DB_PORT,
    sid=config.DB_SID)
db_conn = cx_Oracle.connect(connection_string)

cursor = db_conn.cursor()
```

I don't know much about this, but would having a session/connection pool help here?

Answer (score 2):

If you use a session pool (cx_Oracle.SessionPool) then dead sessions will be replaced whenever they are requested from the pool. That will not help you with existing sessions that have been acquired from the pool. But if you get an error, and you release the session back to the pool and then acquire a session again from the pool you will get a session that can be used. If you want more advanced protection from database failure you will need to explore some of the more advanced techniques that the Oracle Database has to offer like RAC (Real Application Clusters).